# Is $n\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{nx}$ limited for $x\in [0,1]$ and $n\rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, asymptotics

I've got this qustion to answer. I know that answer is no.
My first idea is to use Big O notation, then:

$$ f(n) = n \implies O(f(n)) = n $$
$$ g(n) = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{nx} \implies O(g(n))=?$$

And at the end write something like "Asymptotic growth of $f(n)$ is bigger than $g(n)$ for $x\in [0,1]$ and $n\rightarrow \infty$, so:$$n\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{nx}$$ is not limited"

Does anybody know how to Evaluate $O(g(n))$?
(If yes) Is my idea to approach/prove that problem is correct?

Thank you for advance

Comment: What happens when $x=0$?

Comment: It is more good to write $n\in O(f(n))$, because $O(f(n)) = n$ is not correct. As to your first question, then you can use $f\in O(f)$.

Comment: $n\cdot 1$ is not limited.. Too much of thinking. Thanks

Comment: Do not write $O(f(n)) = $ with $O$ on the left side of an equation.  See explanations of big-$O$ notation.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{2^{nx}}=\cases{\infty, & $x=0$; \\ 0, & $x>0$.}$$
So, the answer is "no".